# Google Pagespeed Third-party usage. Who are 'Research Online'? How do I detect the software?

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

When I scan my Google Cloud compute website with pagespeedtest.net
e.g. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fredbridgeramblers.org.uk%2Fulinks.php

I get an unexpected 3rd party
Research Online 41 KB 106 ms

I expect only Google Analytics.
I have tried running the test from 2 different PCs and get the same result.

Who are Research Online?
How can I detect the code?

When I open the network tab in Chrome or Firefox I cannot see Research Online.
I also ran https://www.webpagetest.org/ and looked in the waterfall view and could not see anything suspicious.
The weekly scan in Google Cloud compute does not find anything suspicious.

I get the same 3rd party on other web pages on the site.

Comment: Have you set up Search Console? I didn't spot anything obvious and have never seen this myself so my first reaction would be that the user agent is somehow affecting it. Set up search console and then use the 'fetch as google' tool, see if you get any additional code within the HTML google pulls back.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I just tried Google Search Console. The page source shown in the google bot is the same as my code.  I then remembered the Flickr pages and wondered if the Research Online was goming from there so I created ulinks_test.php without the menu linking to Photos.  However ,this did not fix the problem either.

Comment: @JohnC did you ever discover an answer to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Undistraction I did not find the answer, but I have not come across the issue since raising this call.

Comment: @JohnC you can find the answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/129899/what-is-research-online-as-displayed-in-chrome-dev-tools-lighthouse/129902#129902 TLDR it is a Chrome bug effecting .org.uk domains.

Answer (score 0):

I had same 'Research Online' issue. Your question the only mention of it I found. But checking 1 hour later it's gone. The report has changed too. Also my desktop pagespeed has increased from 79 to 100 (yee hah!) .

Guesses - Google pagespeed, like much of their product, is more random than they will admit. Or A/B testing.